# paint text with paintEvent()

Tags: html, qt, qt4, qstring, qpainter

i have a program that needs to paint some text with paintEvent().
i've tried this:

```
1. QPainter painter; // painter for the canvas
2. painter.drawText(QPoint location, QString canvasText);
```

where

```
3. QString canvasText = variablesText.append("< b >");
4. variablesText.append((*fieldIter).second.c_str());
5. variablesText.append(":< /b > ");
6. variablesText.append(someValue);
7. variablesText.append("\n");
```

I need the text to be formated, canvasText should look like:

**Some bold text:** some not bold text. (newLine)

**Some bold text 2:**  some not bold text2. (newLine) and that goes on for a while.

The problem i'm having is that a QString can't have HTML code in it, so the text is displayed like:

```
< b>Some bold text:< /b> some not bold text. < b>Some bold text 2: < /b>
some not bold text2.\n
```

Is there a way to use draw in paintEvent to show the text the way i need it? with a QString (or QLabel or something)

I'm using Qt4.

Thanks for the help =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`QTextDocument`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qtextdocument.html) seems like a good fit for what you're after, specifically `setHtml()`. A `QTextDocument` can format your text and paint the result to the screen via your widget's `QPainter`. Something like the below is the simplest possible solution:

```
void Test::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{
  QPainter painter(this);

  QTextDocument doc;
  doc.setHtml("<b>Title</b><p>Body Text</p>");

  doc.drawContents(&painter, rect());
}
```

Bear in mind, however, that this is likely to be very inefficient. You'll probably want to `drawContents()` to a cached `QPixmap` only when your source html changes...

Comment: Thanks @sjwarner, however, i need to give it an specific location to where it needs to be drawn I did this `document->drawContents(&painter, QRect(QPoint.x(), QPoint.y(), rect().width(), rect().height()));` but it doesn't show anything.

Comment: @sjtaheri seems to have got you on the right track, so I'll leave you to it ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you are trying to print HTML formatted text contents in str on `QRect` rect via `QPainter` painter. Do as follows:

```
QString str; // this string contains HTML formatted contents 
QTextDocument * document = new QTextDocument(this) ;
document->setHtml(str) ;

painter.translate( rect.left() , rect.top() ) ;
document->drawContents( &painter , QRect( 0 , 0,  rect.width() , rect.height() ) ;
```

Comment: Thanks @sjtaheri! that works just fine, but i need to give it an specific location that i have stored in a QList. I did this `document->drawContents(&painter, QRect(QPoint.x(), QPoint.y(), rect().width(), rect().height()));` but it doesn't show anything. If i use numbers like `document->drawContents(&painter, QRect(20, 20, rect().width(), rect().height()));` it shows the rect but trimmed. Any thoughts?

Comment: For every point, first, translate it using painter::translate method with point's x and y position as arguments. Then draw the document by calling document->drawContents( &painter , QRect( 0 , 0,  width , height ). width and height should be large enough so the whole text fit in. Finally restore the painter using QPainter::restore method. Repeat this procedure for all points.

Comment: Thanks again @sjtaheri =D I tried that, but it won't show the rest of the qpixmaps i have on the painter, not even if I do the restore :S this is my code: `for (int i = 0; i < pieceRects.size(); ++i) { painter.drawPixmap(pieceRects[i], iconList[i]->getIcon()); QTextDocument *document = new QTextDocument(this); document->setHtml(iconList[i]->getVariablesText()); painter.translate(iconList[i]->getVariablesLocation()); document->drawContents(&painter, rect()); painter.restore();}` The qpixmap is  invisible, if i start clicking, i eventually grab the qpixmap but when i release it fades again. =(